# Vancouver bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

How can I implement the function sort and compress in the [vancouver bibliography style](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/vancouver)? Also, the last reference (`\bibitem{sitoedta}`) of the bibliography ends with a ';' instead of a '.' because it's a shorter reference and I have no access to the missing parts of the entry. How can I fix this?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% document class
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, table, svgnames]{book} %% Silvia: in brackets you put the option 

%% packages
\input{settings/packages}

%% page settings
\input{settings/page}

\pagestyle{fancy} %turn on the style
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

%% own commands
%\newcommand{\tbi}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\input{settings/macros}
\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\underline{\textit{#1}}}
%\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{4cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% TABLE OF CONTENTS

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% INTRODUCTION

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Renal function}

\subsection{Urine composition}

Uremic toxins can be classified in accordance with their physiochemical characteristics, which affect the removal process during dialysis \cite{RefWorks:102, RefWorks:6, RefWorks:94}: % SORT AND COMPRESS doesn't work
\begin{itemize}
\item
small and water-soluble compounds
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
        they display a molecular weight lesser than 500 $Dalton$ ($Da$);
        \item
        the main molecules are urea, creatinine, uric acid and guanidine;
        \item
        they are easily removed through dialysis;
        \item
        they are not necessarily toxic; 
    \end{itemize}
\item
medium size molecules
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
        they are compounds, mostly polypeptides, with relatively high Mw, such as $ \beta_2 $- microglobulin and leptin;
        \item
        they are solely removed with membranes equipped with pores large enough to allow the substances to pass; 
    \end{itemize}
\item
liposoluble and/or protein-bound compounds: 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item
        they display a low Mw, similar to phenols and indoles; 
        \item
        these molecules are predominantly toxic and difficult to be removed by way of the majority of the dialysis methods available nowadays;
        \item
        their removal widely depends on the equilibrium between the free and the occupied sites;
        \item
        for this type of solutes, the use of adsorbent methods may be more effective \cite{RefWorks:9, RefWorks:105, RefWorks:143}. %16-18 cambiare stile bibliografia
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Peritoneal dialysis}

An additional limit is represented by the absence of hydrostatic pressure gradients able to guarantee convective mass exchange; the process is solely diffusive. The control over the removal  of the fluid is obtained though the variation of the dialysate composition, for instance by adding glucose or icodextrin as osmolytes in dialysate \cite{sitoedta}.

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{literature/new}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{RefWorks:102}
Neirynck N, Vanholder R, Schepers E, Eloot S, Pletinck A, Glorieux G.
\newblock An update on uremic toxins.
\newblock Int Urol Nephrol. 2013 Feb;45(1):139--150.

\bibitem{RefWorks:6}
Barreto FC, Stinghen AE, de~Oliveira RB, Franco AT, Moreno AN, Barreto DV,
  et~al.
\newblock The quest for a better understanding of chronic kidney disease
  complications: an update on uremic toxins.
\newblock J Bras Nefrol. 2014 Apr-Jun;36(2):221--235.

\bibitem{RefWorks:94}
Vanholder RC, Eloot S, Glorieux GL.
\newblock Future Avenues to Decrease Uremic Toxin Concentration.
\newblock Am J Kidney Dis. 2016 Apr;67(4):664--676.

\bibitem{RefWorks:9}
Basile C.
\newblock Uremic Toxins: The Case of Protein-Bound Compounds.
\newblock Giornale Italiano di Nefrologia. 2010 Sep-Oct;27(5):498--507.

\bibitem{RefWorks:105}
Lekawanvijit S, Kompa AR, Wang BH, Kelly DJ, Krum H.
\newblock Cardiorenal syndrome: the emerging role of protein-bound uremic
  toxins.
\newblock Circ Res. 2012 Nov 9;111(11):1470--1483.

\bibitem{RefWorks:143}
Ito S, Yoshida M.
\newblock Protein-bound uremic toxins: new culprits of cardiovascular events in
  chronic kidney disease patients.
\newblock Toxins. 2014 Feb 20;6(2):665--678.

\bibitem{sitoedta}
Baxter Healthcare Corporation. EXTRANEAL (icodextrin) Peritoneal Dialysis
  Solution: Risk Evaluation and Mitigation Strategy. 2014;.

\end{thebibliography}
```

From the `.bib` file:

```
@article{RefWorks:102,
    Author = {N. Neirynck and R. Vanholder and E. Schepers and S. Eloot and A. Pletinck and G. Glorieux},
    Journal = {Int Urol Nephrol},
    Month = {Feb},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {139-150},
    Title = {An update on uremic toxins},
    Volume = {45},
    Year = {2013},
}

@article{RefWorks:6,
    author={F. C. Barreto and A. E. Stinghen and R. B. de Oliveira and A. T. Franco and A. N. Moreno and D. V. Barreto and R. Pecoits-Filho and T. B. Drueke and Z. A. Massy},
    year={2014},
    month={Apr-Jun},
    title={The quest for a better understanding of chronic kidney disease complications: an update on uremic toxins},
    journal={J Bras Nefrol},
    volume={36},
    number={2},
    pages={221-235},
}

@article{RefWorks:94,
    Author = {R. C. Vanholder and S. Eloot and G. L. Glorieux},
    Month = {Apr},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {664-676},
    Title = {Future Avenues to Decrease Uremic Toxin Concentration},
    Journal = {Am J Kidney Dis},
    Volume = {67},
    Year = {2016},
}

@article{RefWorks:9,
    author={C. Basile},
    year={2010},
    month={Sep-Oct},
    title={Uremic Toxins: The Case of Protein-Bound Compounds},
    journal={Giornale Italiano di Nefrologia},
    volume={27},
    number={5},
    pages={498-507}
}

@article{RefWorks:105,
    Author = {S. Lekawanvijit and A. R. Kompa and B. H. Wang and D. J. Kelly and H. Krum},
    Journal = {Circ Res},
    Month = {Nov 9},
    Number = {11},
    Pages = {1470-1483},
    Title = {Cardiorenal syndrome: the emerging role of protein-bound uremic toxins},
    Volume = {111},
    Year = {2012},
}

@article{RefWorks:143,
    Author = {S. Ito and M. Yoshida},
    Journal = {Toxins},
    Month = {Feb 20},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {665-678},
    Title = {Protein-bound uremic toxins: new culprits of cardiovascular events in chronic kidney disease patients},
    Volume = {6},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{sitoedta,
    year =   {2014},
    title =  {Baxter Healthcare Corporation. EXTRANEAL (icodextrin) Peritoneal Dialysis Solution: Risk Evaluation and Mitigation Strategy},
}
```

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Why did you undo the formatting? If you don't want other people to edit your post, do it yourself: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to be compilable and add some of the bib entrys to your question too.

Comment: Can you please add the problematic entries from the .bib file?

Comment: Concerning your third question: if you cannot fill all the mandatory fields of an article, don't use an article but something else. Try for example `@misc{sitoedta,` instead.

Comment: @misc works! What about sort and compress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to compress the cites, you could use the `cite` package.
- if you cannot fill all the mandatory fields of an article, don't use an article but something else. Try for example `@misc{sitoedta,` instead.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RefWorks:102,
    Author = {N. Neirynck and R. Vanholder and E. Schepers and S. Eloot and A. Pletinck and G. Glorieux},
    Journal = {Int Urol Nephrol},
    Month = {Feb},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {139-150},
    Title = {An update on uremic toxins},
    Volume = {45},
    Year = {2013},
}

@article{RefWorks:6,
    author={F. C. Barreto and A. E. Stinghen and R. B. de Oliveira and A. T. Franco and A. N. Moreno and D. V. Barreto and R. Pecoits-Filho and T. B. Drueke and Z. A. Massy},
    year={2014},
    month={Apr-Jun},
    title={The quest for a better understanding of chronic kidney disease complications: an update on uremic toxins},
    journal={J Bras Nefrol},
    volume={36},
    number={2},
    pages={221-235},
}

@article{RefWorks:94,
    Author = {R. C. Vanholder and S. Eloot and G. L. Glorieux},
    Month = {Apr},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {664-676},
    Title = {Future Avenues to Decrease Uremic Toxin Concentration},
    Journal = {Am J Kidney Dis},
    Volume = {67},
    Year = {2016},
}

@misc{sitoedta,
    year =   {2014},
    title =  {Baxter Healthcare Corporation. EXTRANEAL (icodextrin) Peritoneal Dialysis Solution: Risk Evaluation and Mitigation Strategy},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\cite{RefWorks:102, RefWorks:6, RefWorks:94}
\cite{sitoedta}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```